# Angular [style] not always working with *ngFor divs

Tags: css, angular, dom, ngfor, ng-style

Welcome, I have Angular application which should look and work like messenger writing all messaages to MySQL.

**The problem is that it looks like this:**
[image: WRONG]

**But should look like this:**
[image: RIGHT]

**component.html fragment:**

```
<div *ngFor="let m of messages" [style.background-color]="m.to===conversationPartnerId ? 'lightgrey' : 'blueviolet'"
         [style.margin-left]="m.to!=conversationPartnerId ? '5%' : '15%'"
         [style.margin-right]="m.to===conversationPartnerId ? '5%' : '15%'"
         style="width: 80%; height: auto; float: left; margin-top: 5%">
      <h3 style="color: white">{{m.text}}</h3>
    </div>
```

**component.ts fragment:**

```
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {

  userKey = null;
  profileToDecide: Profiles;
  matches: Profiles[];
  currentImage: any;
  background: any;
  decisionResponse: any;
  conversationPartnerId: number;
  conversationPartnerName: string;
  messages: Messages[];


LINES OF OTHER METHODS
...
...
...
getMessages(id: number, name: string): void {
    this.setConversationPartnerIdAndName(id, name);
    let registerObject: object;
    registerObject = {
      "key": this.userKey,
      "target": this.conversationPartnerId,
    };
    this.restService.getMessages(registerObject).subscribe(messages => {
      this.messages = messages;
    })
  }

  setConversationPartnerIdAndName(id: number, name: string): void { // Set key and name used in html 
    this.conversationPartnerId = id;                                // ngStyle formatting
    this.conversationPartnerName = name;
  }
```

**JSON from API:**
[image: JSON server response]

Comment: Your code looks ok. Could you create a StackBlitz that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this just set the wrong key, `to` should be `to_id`, this is my demo, you can follow this.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v89nb9?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I have good key, I forgot to tell that I have exported interface with keys: id, from, to, text, date. I'll look at your answer and try again, maybe I wrote something wrong

Comment: I changed exported interface fields 'to' to 'to_id' and 'from' to 'from_id', then in HTML and now it works. I didn't thought that other name in exported in interface can cause this problem. Thanks again. It works!